# How to check server network downtime

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

So I'm running a small server running CentOS and a nextcloud instance. Together with NO-IP I'm able to connect to it from the outside as well.

From time to time I'm noticing I can't connect to my server, not over HTTPS or over SSH. After a minute or so I'm able to connect again.

Is there a way to run a script to find out how many times this happens? I'm also trying to find out where problem originates from. My ISP the Modem or NO-IP, but so far no luck...

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Review logs to check the services or the host remain up and have not been restarted.

Get a monitoring tool that measures access to your services. A good one can be set up in remote sites of interest, and measure performance across multiple paths.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to monitor is to ping from the inside the server to any public url with a timestamp, and output the ping result to a log file. Run it for a day or two then you could see when the downtime occurs. Check against the system log file to find the root cause.

```
ping google.com | awk '/^[0-9]+ bytes from / { "date" | getline pong; close("date"); print pong":",$0; }' ＞/tmp/pingtest.log
```

A better way is to setup Zabbix to monitor your server and website. IMO it is pretty simple to setup Zabbix, you may follow the instruction on this website on how to do it:
https://sysadminwork.com/monitoring-website-with-zabbix/